# I am having an error whilst installing pyspark, how can I fix it?

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to install and practice pyspark. But during installation and entering pyspark-shell, I get the error below.

```
C:\Windows\System32>spark-shell
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
ReplGlobal.abort: bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 48445
[init] error:
  bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 48445
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
     library version: version 2.12.15
    compiler version: version 2.12.15
  reconstructed args: -classpath  -Yrepl-class-based -Yrepl-outdir C:\Users\Ebi Kare Ganranwei\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-b51c6ad4-8d78-4aff-804a-c31d869d79e7\repl-8a94e77c-5fc5-4f91-b040-e50cc0dca2c7

  last tree to typer: EmptyTree
       tree position: <unknown>
            tree tpe: <notype>
              symbol: null
           call site: <none> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==


Exception in thread "main" scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:
  bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 48445
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
     library version: version 2.12.15
    compiler version: version 2.12.15
  reconstructed args: -classpath  -Yrepl-class-based -Yrepl-outdir C:\Users\Ebi Kare Ganranwei\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-b51c6ad4-8d78-4aff-804a-c31d869d79e7\repl-8a94e77c-5fc5-4f91-b040-e50cc0dca2c7

  last tree to typer: EmptyTree
       tree position: <unknown>
            tree tpe: <notype>
              symbol: null
           call site: <none> in <none>

== Source file context for tree position ==


        at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort(Reporting.scala:69)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort$(Reporting.scala:65)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anon$2.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ReplGlobal$$super$abort(IMain.scala:239)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ReplGlobal.abort(ReplGlobal.scala:31)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ReplGlobal.abort$(ReplGlobal.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anon$2.abort(IMain.scala:239)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.errorBadIndex(ClassfileParser.scala:386)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getExternalName(ClassfileParser.scala:250)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.readParamNames$1(ClassfileParser.scala:841)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttribute$1(ClassfileParser.scala:847)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parseAttributes$7(ClassfileParser.scala:921)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttributes(ClassfileParser.scala:921)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseMethod(ClassfileParser.scala:623)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parseClass$4(ClassfileParser.scala:536)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:536)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$2(ClassfileParser.scala:161)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$1(ClassfileParser.scala:147)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:130)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:343)
        at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:250)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.completeInfo(Symbols.scala:1542)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions.scala$reflect$internal$Definitions$$enterNewMethod(Definitions.scala:49)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1134)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus(Definitions.scala:1134)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1438)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods(Definitions.scala:1420)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1450)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1450)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1506)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1213)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain._initialize(IMain.scala:124)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.initializeSynchronous(IMain.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$10(SparkILoop.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:984)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:191)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1072)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1081)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Comment: Related? https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7002

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a docker image to start Jupyter Notebook or Lab. This is by far the least complicated method.

1. Install Docker Engine for your OS
2. Once Docker is installed, you can run the following in the command line:

docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook

The above will run all the necessary components. You will just need to point your browser to http://localhost:8888

For Reference:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/
- https://charlesreid1.com/wiki/Docker/Jupyter_PySpark
- https://medium.com/@suci/running-pyspark-on-jupyter-notebook-with-docker-602b18ac4494